# How to start multiple SSH sessions with single password?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords

I'm a system administrator in a company based in Tunisia. I control 50+ Raspberry Pis with Debian Jessie. I connect frequently over SSH with the same password for  all of them.

**Is there any solution to use the password once and not enter it again?**

My PC: gnome-Ubuntu 16.04
Raspberry Pis: Jessie arm6vl

Comment: I would write my own script file that will ssh into X hosts, pass your password on, and issue the same command to all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has a package called sshpass.
Install it on Ubuntu 16.04 like this:

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

And use it like this:

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host
```

For multiple hosts you can do something like:

```
for host in hostname1 hostname2 hostname3; do \
    sshpass -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@${host} "hostname; df -h; echo"; done
```

The StrictHostKeyChecking disables the usual SSH check that the remote machine is in your list of known hosts; if you are deploying a Pi farm this will probably be the case. When using sshpass, instead of displaying the message 'The authenticity of host xxxx can't be established', the command silently fails without this option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend to use [ssh keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) instead of a password.

You create a pair of keys (private/public), install the public key on each of your RaspPi's, and the private key on your Ubuntu computer.

See e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61557/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-authentication-keys) or google for lots of howto's.